# Cordova Android 6 InAppBrowser Error

Tags: android, cordova, browser, plugins

I tried to use this plugin but it can't work on Android 6, it works on previous android on the emulator.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Do you know how to make it works on Android 6? Permission issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Updated to Crosswalk 2.2.0 and the problem is thankfully gone. 
same with deviceready more than 5sec error.